# Implementing raw code for back-propagation neural network

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I want to implement back-propagation neural network algorithm in raw code, not using any library as my interest to understand in depth operations/customization of this algorithm.

In this regard, I need to follow step-by-step simulation of back-propagation algorithm. More precisely, what code I should write in R language to each of steps in back-propagation neural network. Can anyone show me the close explanation of steps in this algorithm.

I don't need any code. Just show me what operations is done in each steps.

> FYI: for reviewers, this is not my assignment. I'm doing my assignments using *neuralnet* library. Please leave a comment before any report.

Comment: Would a step by step derivation of a vanilla neural network help you?

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan Can you provide any example?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see how the internals work, the best resource for a beginner, that I have found, is [this series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxe2T-V8XRs&feature=youtu.be&list=PLiaHhY2iBX9hdHaRr6b7XevZtgZRa1PoU) by Welch Labs.  It goes through each step of a basic feed-forward backpropogation model including the calculus steps so you understand what is happening during each step.  It is all done in Python but you can definitely convert it to R if that is your goal.  That would be a great learning exercise.